# osx yosemite - failure to brew install imagemagick, with brew link error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, osx-yosemite

I was building a Rails project which requires imagemagick.
I have posted the error during installation below:

```
$brew install imagemagick
Error: You must `brew link jpeg' before imagemagick can be installed

$brew link jpeg
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d...
Error: Could not symlink lib/libjpeg.a
Target /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a'
```

I tried to remove it, link jpeg, and install again. But it is not working. While I tried to attach a photo in my rails application, it still said 'please install imagemagick'.

Running OSX 10.10.5, anyone knows how to fix it?

**Edit:**

I tried to reinstall it from source, but got the following errors.

```
$brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
==> Downloading http://www.imagemagick.org/download/releases/ImageMagick-6.9.1-1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagem
==> make install
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [magick/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [install] Error 2
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
```

But I didn't install MacPorts or Fink. Any solution?

**Edit2:**

After I removed jpeg and reinstalled imagemagick, it still fails. Any idea from this info?

```
$brew info imagemagick
imagemagick: stable 6.9.1-10 (bottled), HEAD
Tools and libraries to manipulate images in many formats
http://www.imagemagick.org
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.1-10 (1447 files, 22M)
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/imagemagick.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: xz ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: xz ✔, libtool ✔
Recommended: jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libtiff ✔, freetype ✔
Optional: fontconfig ✘, little-cms ✘, little-cms2 ✘, libwmf ✘, librsvg ✘, liblqr ✘, openexr ✘, ghostscript ✘, webp ✘, fftw ✘, pango ✘
==> Options
--with-fftw
    Compile with FFTW support
--with-fontconfig
    Build with fontconfig support
--with-ghostscript
    Build with ghostscript support
--with-hdri
    Compile with HDRI support
--with-jp2
    Compile with Jpeg2000 support
--with-liblqr
    Build with liblqr support
--with-librsvg
    Build with librsvg support
--with-libwmf
    Build with libwmf support
--with-little-cms
    Build with little-cms support
--with-little-cms2
    Build with little-cms2 support
--with-openexr
    Build with openexr support
--with-openmp
    Compile with OpenMP support
--with-pango
    Build with pango support
--with-perl
    enable build/install of PerlMagick
--with-quantum-depth-16
    Compile with a quantum depth of 16 bit
--with-quantum-depth-32
    Compile with a quantum depth of 32 bit
--with-quantum-depth-8
    Compile with a quantum depth of 8 bit
--with-webp
    Build with webp support
--with-x11
    Build with x11 support
--without-freetype
    Build without freetype support
--without-jpeg
    Build without jpeg support
--without-libpng
    Build without libpng support
--without-libtiff
    Build without libtiff support
--without-magick-plus-plus
    disable build/install of Magick++
--without-opencl
    Disable OpenCL
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

Comment: You removed '/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a' and it still couldn't link? Can you confirm that its removed, e.g. `ls /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.a`?

Comment: Yes, it is removed. Then I tried to install imagemagick again, it automatically reinstall jpeg for me. But imagemagicks still doesn't work properly.

Comment: finally i make it through, by reinstalling rails